# how to convert back from pixel coordinates to x,y coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, shapely

Here is what I have done to project shapely points to pixel coordinates :

```
#shapely list of points
points= ['POINT (656822.0796426814 -185003.7243437266)', 'POINT 
(656917.7545657885 -184985.6672704536)', 'POINT (656997.7888963958 
-185001.578684116)']

#converting shapely list to np array
coords_list = [[geom.xy[0][0], geom.xy[1][0]] for geom in points ]
coords = np.array(coords_list)

# Reproject shapefile points to numpy coordinate system
proj_im = gdal.Open(input.tif')
geoinformation = proj_im.GetGeoTransform()

xorigin = geoinformation[0]
yorigin = geoinformation[3]
pix_size = abs(geoinformation[1])

coords_unp = np.roll(np.column_stack(((coords[:, 0] - xorigin) / pix_size, \
                                      (yorigin - coords[:, 1])/pix_size)),1, 1)
print(coord_unp)
>> [[ 2359.02892404  1537.68823732]
   [ 2085.43690476  2987.30828439]
   [ 2326.51892994  4199.94965723]]
```

How do I convert back from pixel coordinates to lat,lon?

Comment: Have you tried gdalwarp for reprojecting your image ? http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html

Answer (score 1):

you have to know what your origin projection is to convert coordinates, since you are using python there is a library Pyproj that does this, ( I'll assume in this code that your origin projection is the pseudo mercator EPSG:3857 which unit is the meter )

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform
import shapely.geometry as geom

inProj = Proj(init='epsg:3857')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')

points_in_lat_lon = []
for point in points:
     x, y = point.coords[0]
     lat, lon = transform(inProj, outProj, x, y)
     points_in_lat_lon.append(geom.Point([lat, lon])
```

Comment: I dnt want to change the projection, I want to convert Cartesian coordinates(x,y) to lat, long values

Comment: then I think you should change the question to how to convert back from pixel coordinates to x,y coordinates, and have you tried reversing the equation you used in `np.roll` ?

Comment: I Changed the topic of question. yes i have tried reversing that equation, but it didn't work.